# Apache redirect URL to Subdirectory

Tags: angular, apache, apache2

I have a problem serving an Angular application using Apache in a subdirectory.

Because another Applicatition is running in the root directory, I serve the Angular application in a subdirectory in the /var/www/html folder. If I try to access the index.html using the correct path in the browser, the Angular application does not work because of mismatched paths, e.g. loading assets (the application looks in the root directory). If the Angular application is deployed in the root folder of Apache the application works.

Is there a possibility to map e.g. /example to the example directory but handling the directory if it would be the root directory?

Is there another way how I would solve this issue in the correct way?

I already found that Apache offers virtual hosts and that there is the possibilty to define URL rewrites, but I did not find out how to solve this problem or if those utilitys may help me.

Thanks a lot for your feedback / help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.